# RxJS/Angular 11 wait for 2 observables complete and errors handling

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-observables

I need wait for two requests (observables) and do some things.
What i need:

1. Wait for requests (observables) end
2. If one of them failed - display one error
3. If both of them failed - display second error
4. If first success - do some things
5. If second success - do some things

i can combine 4 and 5 if that matter for errors handling.

I tried to use `forkJoin` but it fails at all if one of requests failed.
I tried to use `concat` but it works the same as `forkJoin`
I tried to use `combineLatestWith` but it doesn't display errors at all as `combineLatest`
Finally i tried to use next:

```
const firstRequest$ = this.doFirstRequest(searchRequest);
const secondRequest$ = this.doSecondRequest(searchRequest);
combineLatest([firstRequest$, secondRequest$]).subscribe(([res1, res2]) => {
  console.log(res1, res2);
}, err => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

and now i got only both success results and didn't get any error
What im missing?

Answer (score 3):

catch your errors at the request level and transform them into something usable:

```
const firstRequest$ = this.doFirstRequest(searchRequest).pipe(
  catchError(error => of({error})) 
);
const secondRequest$ = this.doSecondRequest(searchRequest).pipe(
  catchError(error => of({error}))
);
forkJoin([firstRequest$, secondRequest$]).subscribe(([res1, res2]) => {
  if (res1.error && res2.error) {
    // both failed
  } else if (res1.error || res2.error) {
    // one failed
  }
  if (!res1.error) {
    // req 1 success 
  }
  if (!res2.error) {
    // req 2 success
  }
  // whatever you need to do now that they're both done
}, err => {
  // can't get here now
});
```

Comment: thx for your answer! Tell me please, in this example if error happened in firstRequest and secondRequest will be displayed two errors right? Because i need just one)

Comment: ah ok. that is the case. one second, I can adjust it.

Comment: do you need the actual error responses?

Comment: yes, i need, i need to know error status code from the body

Comment: then you just adjust your `catchError` to map it to contain whatever you need and your logic in the subscribe handler appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to use `forkJoin` for this use case, See [ForkJoin docs](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin).
2. Add `catchError` operator to the first stream to handle the first request
3. Add another `catchError` operator to the second stream to handle it
4. Add `tap` operator to the first stream 1
5. Add another `tap` operator to the first stream 2

```js
const firstRequest$ = this.doFirstRequest(searchRequest).pipe(
  tap(() => {
    // DO SOMETHING STREAM 1 REGARDLESS OF STREAM 2
  }),
  catchError((e => {
    console.error('Error from stream 1', e);
    return of(null);
  });
);

const secondRequest$ = this.doFirstRequest(searchRequest).pipe(
  tap(() => {
    // DO SOMETHING STREAM 2 REGARDLESS OF STREAM 1
  }),
  catchError((e => {
    console.error('Error from stream 2', e);
    return of(null);
  });
);

forkJoin([firstRequest$, secondRequest$]).subscribe(([res1, res2]) => {
  console.log('All done');

  if (res1) {
    // DO SOMETHING STREAM 1 AFTER ALL STREAMS ARE DONE
  }

  if (res21) {
    // DO SOMETHING STREAM 2 AFTER ALL STREAMS ARE DONE
  }
});
```

Comment: if something in `forkJoin` emits `EMPTY`, I do not believe the subscribe handler will ever trigger.

Comment: You're right, returning a null observable should do it! I updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

I had a case where one request normally takes much longer than the other, so in the success case I don't want to have to wait for both requests to finish before continuing. As soon as one request finishes, I want to show the received data to the user.
But the error handling needed to be different if both requests failed, than if just one failed or when both succeeded.

So I did this:

```
getRequestASucceeded$ = new ReplaySubject<boolean>(1);

this.getRequestA()
    .subscribe( dataA => {
       this.getRequestASucceeded$.next(true);
       // continue with dataA
     },
     (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        this.getRequestASucceeded$.next(false);
      }
   );

this.getRequestB()
    .subscribe( dataB => {
       
       // continue with dataB

       this.getRequestASucceeded$.subscribe( hasSucceeded => {
          if (hasSucceeded) {
            // Both Request succeeded
          else {
            // RequestA failed, RequestB succeeded
          }
     },
     (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        
        this.getRequestASucceeded$.subscribe( hasSucceeded => {
          if (hasSucceeded) {
            // RequestA succeeded, RequestB failed
          else {
            // Both Request failed
          }
      }
   );
```

The Errors are only processed after both requests finished, but the individaul data can get processed right away.